# Custom Archive - hide posts until a search is made?

Tags: custom-post-types, search, archives

I have a Custom Post Type with an Archive page. I have a filter form on the page so the user can select some options and then find matching results.

How can I stop posts being displayed (using the loop) until a filter search is made by the user?

Comment: How are you doing the filtering?

Comment: fetching posts that have certain taxonomy terms, using the meta_query WP_Query args.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this easily to be achieved by checking if ?s= is set ?
You do have to output the results of this search on the same page, by using the post archive link as action url.

`if ( isset( $_GET[s] ) {
    // show posts
}`